# How to connect API as data source in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, grafana, tableau-desktop, wwdc

I need to use two data sources. One is SQL and another one is the response from a rest API.

I tried to implement WDC, but it needs an HTML and user need to interact with UI and getting the response.

But I don't want to create a html page.

Is there any way to use an API response as a data source in Tableau?

Comment: No. Write your API response to a flat file or ingest into a db and connect to that.

Comment: In grafana, I saw one blog that uses rest api as data source.

You are saying that, there is no way to use a rest api response as data source in tableau. Is it right?

Comment: You can write a web data connector

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I wrote one WDC. But it needs an HTML page and and user need to interact with the UI. After that data fetch occurs. But I don't need an HTML stuff. Is it possible?

Comment: I’d look on the community forums on tableau’s site to see if there is a way cut out the html step.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can not use API directly as a data source but you should build a pipeline to transform this into flat-file o populate a database table.

The alternative answer is to use Python to connect to the REST API. You can choose to use TabPy or follow some pre-build solution [like this one](https://tableauandbehold.com/2019/12/30/web-services-rest-apis-as-a-data-source-in-tableau-a-postgresql-python-solution/). Personally, I don't know how the performances could be.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try with TabPy and then pre-build solution.

Comment: Hi, I tried TabPy, but it only for creating a new calculated field. Is it right?
But I want a table or a datasource.